# Identifier for Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, xcode6

From where in Xcode 6 I can give Identifier Name to the Tab bar controller.

Here is my screenshot of Tab bar controller and attribute inspector
I can't find the identifier

[image]

Answer (score 0):

go to *Identity inspector* is at **3rd tab**.

[image]

Comment: but there is no identifier

Comment: what identifier, you'r looking for?

Comment: I got it. In Xcode 5 it's Identifier but in Xcode 6 apple change it to System item

Comment: actually I am not finding identity inspector I was finding system item for the tab bar i.e. Favourite, feature, downloads etc. In Xcode 5 it is in attribute inspector and named identifier but I updated to Xcode 6 so in attribute inspector -> identifier becomes system item

Answer (score 0):

To change the tab bar title and icon you need to change the identifier. the default tab bar doesn't have a icon and title has default item 1 name.
but if you want to change something else like favourite, featured, downloads etc. then

You can change it in **Xcode 5**
Attribut Inspector -> *identifier*

You can change it in **Xcode 6**
Attribute Inspector -> *System item*